# How to auto-generate new passwords for old GridDB database users?

Tags: python, sql, database, griddb

As a database administrator, I can change the password of any user of a database, and the user can also change it themself. However, I have a database representing all the users of a database, their passwords, and when the password was changed last. For security reasons, I need to change the password of those users whose passwords have been changed a very long time ago (like 2 years). But I need the new passwords to be auto-generated, using the user name and some characters. Is that possible in Python GridDB?

The GridDB documentation says I can change the password of a general user this way:

```sql
SET PASSWORD [FOR user_name ] = 'password_string';
```

However, I don't know how to use that statement to (maybe) loop through all the users in the database  and change their passwords that way.

For a database like this:

```py
"""
id |   user  |   password   | date_last_changed
===+=========+==============+===================
 0 | user_x9 | jb@p39h13+$% | 2022/12/24 12:42
 1 | user_a3 | f34*JSghb#!2 | 2011/05/10 10:55
 2 | user_d3 | foshLHF!@#j1 | 2017/10/23 03:53
 3 | user_f5 | 23HHBldfbf#! | 2023/01/21 14:11
 4 | user_a2 | 12*&p3H13-1f | 2020/01/05 17:08
 5 | user_g1 | @3DFSfgs!&^3 | 2021/02/27 04:09

"""
```

The solution should change the password for all the users except `user_x9`, `user_f5`, and `user_g1`.
By the way, I'm using the GridDB Python client for this. Since it supports some SQL statements, I'm sure there is a way to get it to work.

Thanks a lot for your help!